# Where to find exectuable ./configure - PHP Debian

Tags: php, configuration, web-config

I need to install a module in PHP (OCI8), and to do so, I'm required to configure php with:

`./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib`
(Extracted from http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php)

However I can't find the location of `./configure` for php... I just need its location.

I'm on a Debian 8 Machine, with Apache2.

Thanks very much!

Comment: you have to download the source of php http://php.net/downloads.php and then extact it and in the dir you find it

Comment: Or you could just install it from PECL (see the section headed `Installing OCI8 from PECL`) further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using the pecl instalation

`sudo pecl install oci8`

Comment: It says that no releases are available :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your using a Debian based linux.
The procedure to install a PHP module is classically compose of 4 steps :

- phpize
- ./configure
- make
- make install

Your missing command is **phpize**, which will generate the ./configuration file required for your environment.